# How to remove values from one df based on the second df

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I remove duplicate values from dataset 2 based on values from dataset1?

My dataset1:

```
number
2345
2234
1111
```

My dataset2:

```
number   name
2345      kk
2121      ll
1111      ms
9999      rr
```

I have tried this code but I can still find some values from the dataset1 that should be removed from dataset2.

```
filter(df2, df2$number %in% df1$number = TRUE)
```

Comment: `anti_join(df2, df1)` or `filter(df2, !number %in% df1$number)`. (Want to remove the duplicates, so we need `!`, and definitely not `== TRUE`.

Comment: Yeah something like `df2[!df2$number %in% df1$number,]`

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
> df
  number
1   2345
2   2234
3   1111
> df1
  number name
1   2345   kk
2   2121   ll
3   1111   ms
4   9999   rr

> df1[!(df1$number %in% df$number),]
  number name
2   2121   ll
4   9999   rr
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
> subset(df2, ! number %in% df1$number)
  number name
2   2121   ll
4   9999   rr
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(number = c(2345, 2234, 1111)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(number = c(2345, 2121, 1111, 9999), name = c("kk",
"ll", "ms", "rr")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```